# Sun FtpClient or Jakarta FtpClient

Tags: java, ftp

Its been years since I've had to ftp a file from java so I'm a bit out of touch with the possibilities.  The documentation I've found lists two possibilities for my use.  The standard Sun ftp implementation and the Jakarta ftp solution from Apache.

I need to ftp images, text files, & PDF files, possibly changing the name of the file from what it is locally to something else on the remote server.

I'm sure everyone has an opinion but can anyone offer concrete reasoning to go with one over the other?  Is there something else I should be looking into?

Comment: I will read each and every comment and I thank all of you in advance for taking the time to help out.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the Sun solution so I cannot give you comparison points, but I can say from personal experience that the [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/net/) library is a reliable and safe bet to go with. It does pretty much everything you could look for in an embeddable FTP client API, plus it gives you access to other nice networking API's as well.